# How to store user meta data?

Tags: 8, users, entities, database

I've seen that it was possible to store custom meta data in Drupal 7 but I didn't find the equivalent for Drupal 8 ?

https://martsie.github.io/2015/03/04/drupal-how-to-use-user-data/

The data that I need to store is temporary user data that might differ from each users and it's not needed to put it as field (no sql query needed).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the user.data service

```
\Drupal::service('user.data')->set('mymodule', $uid, 'some_key', 'some_value');
```

You can then retrieve it with the same service:

```
$some_key = \Drupal::service('user.data')->get('mymodule', $uid, 'some_key');
```

Comment: The relevant changelog page - https://www.drupal.org/node/1852360

Comment: Does this get deleted by itself? or how would you delete it?

Comment: It gets deleted automatically when a user gets deleted or when a module is uninstalled.

Comment: I didn't know that about the module un-installation. That's good information!